# MVC5 to MVC6 converstion can't get RoleManager to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, role-manager

I am trying to upgrade an MVC 5 application to MVC 6. The only thing in the 5 application is the ability to administrate Users and Roles. It is a "template" we created at work to wrap around all MVC projects to give them all the "login, register, and roles" stuff you need for security. It works well. However, we need MVC 6 version too.

We were able to get MVC 6 installed with single user authentication and now I am trying to port over the Roles process from the working MVC 5 application.

My RolesManagementController.cs works in 5, but in 6 I get a red line under "**RoleManager(IdentityRole)**"

[image]

Also, red lines under "**.RoleExists(**" and "**.Update**").
[image]

Here are my using statements in 6 version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MVC6.Models;
```

and my using statements in 5 version are not that much different.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Donut5.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new version of Asp.net (Asp.net 5) those methods became async. you should make your method `async` and return `Task<T>` or just `Task` and call role manager methods with the `await` keyword

```
await _rolesManager.RoleExistsAsync(...)
await _rolesManager.UpdateAsync(...)
```

Example:

```
public async Task MethodName()
{
    var role = await _rolesManager.RoleExistsAsync(...);
    await _rolesManager.UpdateAsync(...);
}
```

Comment: Yes. That helped a whole bunch. Did away with a ton of problems.